# Calculating overtime using rows from 3 different tables

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers, sqlplus

I'm fairly new to SQL and I am trying to create a trigger to calculate overtime worked by subtracting hours contracted (`GRADE_HOURS`) in the `COMPANY_GRADE` table from hours worked (`TIMESHEET_HOURS`) in the `COMPANY_TIMESHEET` table. This will then go into the `TIMESHEET_OT` column of the `COMPANY_TIMESHEET` table whenever a row is inserted into the `COMPANY_TIMESHEET` table.

The tables concerned are as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE COMPANY_TIMESHEET
( 
timesheet_ID number(3) constraint timesheet_pk primary key, 
Timesheet_emp number(3) constraint timesheet_empnotnull not null references company_employee, 
Timesheet_wc date constraint timesheet_wcnotnull not null, 
Timesheet_hours number(2), 
Timesheet_OT number(2) default 0, 
Timesheet_approved number(3) references company_employee 
); 

CREATE TABLE COMPANY_GRADE
( 
grade_ID number(3) constraint grade_pk primary key, 
Grade_rate number(5,2) constraint grade_ratenotnull not null, 
Grade_hours number(2) 
) ; 

CREATE TABLE COMPANY_EMPLOYEE 
( 
emp_ID number(3) constraint emp_pk primary key, 
Emp_firstname varchar2(50) constraint emp_firstnamenotnull not null, 
Emp_surname varchar2(50), 
Emp_department number(2) constraint employeeFKdepartment references company_department, 
emp_street varchar2(50),
emp_town varchar2(50), 
emp_district varchar2(50), 
Emp_grade number(3) default 4 constraint checkempgrade check (Emp_grade between 1 and 9) references company_grade, 
Emp_site varchar2(30) default 'LONDON' 
);
```

I would appreciate any help as I have been trying for many hours now only to be met by error after error.

I have tried numerous variations of this as a starting block to try and pass the hours contracted into a variable to then subtract from another variable:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trg_ot
BEFORE INSERT ON company_timesheet
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE t_contracted NUMBER;
BEGIN
    SELECT grade_hours INTO t_contracted
    FROM company_grade
    WHERE company_employee.emp_id = :new.timesheet_emp;
END;
/
```

Comment: Your question is tagged MyQL and SQL Server.  Yet the code looks more like Oracle than either of those two databases.  I'm removing the database-specific tags.  Please tag the question with the actual database you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trg_ot
BEFORE INSERT ON company_timesheet
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE t_contracted NUMBER;
BEGIN
  SELECT g.grade_hours
  INTO   t_contracted
  FROM   company_grade g
         INNER JOIN
         company_employee e
         ON ( e.emp_grade = g.grade_id )
  WHERE  e.emp_id = :new.timesheet_emp;

  :new.timesheet_ot := :new.timesheet_hours - t_contracted;
END;
/
```